# Find all $x \in R$ that satisfy the inequality $|4x − 3| \le 11$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find all $x \in R$ that satisfy the inequality $|4x − 3| \le 11$

good day, I am having a hard time solving this question I need a little help please.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Use the fact: $|x|\le a\implies -a\le x\le a$.

Comment: @AidenChow i have tried using the axioms to solve it i really dont understand

Comment: A standard approach to solve absolute value problems is to break it into two cases.  One where the object inside the bracket is positive and one where it is negative.  In the case where you assume that $4x-3$ is negative, $|4x-3| = 3-4x.$  A different approach is to square both sides.

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$.

Comment: The way I like to think about this: factor out a 4 so you’re looking for the $x$ satisfying $|x-3/4|\leq11/4$. In this guise you’re looking for all $x$ which are a distance no more than $11/4$ from $3/4$, and of course this is the interval $[3/4-11/4,3/4+11/4]=[-2,7/2]$.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}|4x-3|&\le 11\\-11\le4x-3&\le11\\-8\le4x&\le14\\-2\le x&\le\dfrac72\\x&\in\left[-2,\dfrac72\right]\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

We have two cases to consider: if $4x-3<0$ and if $4x-3\geq 0$ (note that the case where $4x-3 = 0$ can be examined together with either $<0$ or $>0$, since $0$ is not positive or negative).

The 'pivot point' where $4x-3=0$ is at $x=3/4$. Thus, we can split our question into cases where $x<3/4$ and those where $x>3/4$. Let us do the former case:

Suppose $x<3/4$. Then $4x-3<0$ and therefore $|4x-3| = -(4x-3)$. Thus, we must solve the inequality $-(4x-3)\leq 11$. We have
\begin{align*}
-(4x-3)
&\leq 11
\\
-4x+3
&\leq 11
\\
-8
&\leq 4x
\\
-2
&\leq x.
\end{align*}
Great. However, we mustn't forget our original assumption: that $x<3/4$. Combining these two inequalities, we see that all $x\in [-2,3/4)$ satisfy our inequality.

I'll leave the $x>3/4$ case to you.

Comment: Please note, that $-8\leq 4x \Rightarrow x\geq -2$

Comment: @callculus42 Fair, my bad on that.

Comment: Flaws can happen everywhere, everytime by anybody. At the end your method and result is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Case 1: When $4x-3\ge 0 \implies  x\ge 3/4$, the the eq. becomes $4x-3\le 11 \implies x\le 7/2$, the overlap of the two intervals is $[3/4,7/2]$.

Case 2: When $4x-3<0 \implies x<3/4$, now the eq. becomes $-(4x-3)\le 11 \implies x \ge -2$, the overlap of the two intervals is   $[-2,3/4)$.

The union of these two intervals gives $x \in [-2, 7/2]$, the final answer.

Also, $|4x-3\le 11 \implies -11\le (4x-3) \le 11 \implies  -8x \le 4x \le 14 \implies -2 \le x\le 7/2.$

Comment: Please check your calculation.

Comment: Thanks I have corrected it now.

Comment: In your penultimate step, you meant to write $-8 \leq 4x \leq 14$.  At the start of the same line, you are missing an absolute value bar in the inequality $|4x - 3| \leq 11$.

Comment: Thanks I corrected it now.

Answer (score 0):

If $0\leq a\leq b$ then $a^2\le b^2$, so you can square your inequality:

$$|4x-3|^2\leq 11^2$$
$$(4x-3)^2\leq 121$$
$$16x^2-24x+9\leq 121$$
$$16x^2-24x-112\leq 0\;\;\;/:8$$
$$2x^2-3x-14\leq 0$$
$$(2x-7)(x+2)\leq 0$$
$$...$$